# Paperclip multiple spoof media type depending of 'file' version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have an application managing some files like `.blend` files.

`.blend` is not a *standard* mime type, so I add this options into `config/environment.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings][:blend] = "application/octet-stream"
```

The value `"application/octet-stream"` is the value returned by the command

```
$ file -b --mime 'x.blend'
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
$ file -v
file-5.11
```

The issue I have is that the application is deployed on several servers, and they have not the same `file` version. For example, in an other server:

```
$ file -b --mime 'x.blend'
binary; charset=binary
$ file -v
file-5.17
```

So Paperclip detects a *spoof*

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename x.blend ([]), content type discovered from file command: binary. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

I tried to set content_type_mapping as an array (`["application/octet-stream", "binary"]`) but it doesn't work.

Have you any idea? Is it possible to disable this spoof check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For thoses having same issue, my solution to allows multiple mappings was just accepted by Paperclip. You just have to get the last version of it.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/ea142d80eb2f87c5ce7597026a58cd873d9de3a3